# Guardar fecha actual en una variable mysql

Tags: mysql, date, set

Estoy haciendo un procedimiento en MySql para crear folios en mi tabla cotización según los dos dígitos del mes actual + los dos últimos del año actual+ el índice de cotización algo así **C1119001** en donde el 001 hace referencia al indice 1 de mi tabla, el problema es que me manda un error *You have an error in your SQL syntax; it seems the error is around: 'if( ( SELECT COUNT(*) from `t_cotizaciones` LIMIT ' at line..*.

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER PROCEDURE `crearFolio`( id_cliente int (100))

BEGIN
if((SELECT COUNT(*) from `t_cotizaciones` LIMIT 1)=0)
THEN 
set @folio := select concat('','C',Date_format(now(),'%m%y'),'001')

ELSE
if((SELECT MAX(id) from `t_cotizaciones` LIMIT 1)<=10)
THEN
set @var := concat("00",(SELECT MAX(id) from `t_cotizaciones` LIMIT 1)+1),
set @folio:=select concat('','C',Date_format(now(),'%m%y'),@var);

ELSEIF((SELECT MAX(id) from `t_cotizaciones` LIMIT 1)<100)
THEN
set @var := concat("0",(SELECT MAX(id) from `t_cotizaciones` LIMIT 1)+1) 
set @folio:=select concat('','C',Date_format(now(),'%m%y'),@var);

ELSE
set @var := concat((SELECT MAX(id) from `t_cotizaciones` LIMIT 1)+1) 
set @folio:= @folio := select concat('','C',Date_format(now(),'%m%y'),@var);
END if;
end if;

INSERT into `t_cotizaciones`(`id`, `folio`, `id_cliente`, `fecha`, `estatus`)values(null,@folio , id_cliente, now(),'1');

SELECT id FROM `t_cotizaciones` where folio = @folio;
END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas haciendo mal la consulta, la debes de dividir de la siguiente forma:
Primero declara una variable para introducir al MaximoID

```
DECLARE vMaxid  INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE folio VARCHAR(3);
DECLARE fecha VARCHAR(4);
```

Después haces la consulta y con la sentencia INTO, el resultado lo introduces en la variable vMaxid, no necesitas el LIMIT, con la funcion MAX, siempre te trae 1 solo registro

```
SELECT MAX(id) INTO vMaxid from `t_cotizaciones`;
```

Ahora sí, ya podrás usar tu IF

```
if( vMaxid  <=10)
```

**Para la cuestion de la fecha es simplemente con la función DATE_FORMAT, %m = mes, %y= ultimos dos digitos del año :**

```
SET fecha = DATE_FORMAT(now(),'%m%y');
```

Cabe mencionar que en lugar de usar tanto IF, pudieras usar la funcion LPAD, para los ceros a la izquiera:

```
SET folio = LPAD(vMaxid,3,"0");
```

Que traducida quiere decir que llenara con cero, hasta que su longitud sea de 3 caracteres, es decir si vMaxid es 100, no insertara ningún cero

La tabla con un triger seria:

```
CREATE TABLE t_cotizaciones (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  folio varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  id_cliente int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  fecha timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  estatus varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE  TRIGGER crearFolio BEFORE INSERT ON t_cotizaciones FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
SELECT MAX(id) INTO @id from t_cotizaciones;
/*Si la tabla no tiene registros mandara NULL, como id*/
SET @id = IFNULL(@id+1,1) ;
SET NEW.folio = CONCAT('C',DATE_FORMAT(now(),'%m%y'),LPAD(@id,3,'0'));
END;
```

Solo tienes que llenar los demas datos, y el folio se crea automatico

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]